# Binding of multiple variables after cancel and re-selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've made the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".test_uebergabe").click(function() {
    var groupName = $(this).data('groupname');
    var groupid = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.modal-body').html(groupName);
    $('#dataModal').modal({
      show: true
    });

    $(".test_uebergabe_route").click(function() {
      alert(groupid);
    });
  });
});
```

When `test_uebergabe` is clicked, I get two variables and the modal opens with `groupname`. In the modal are two buttons, cancel and save. When I click on save, the script gives me back the `groupid`. This is correct. But when I click cancel and choose another `test_uebergabe` button, I get back the new `groupid` and the choosen `groupid` before. Why? What I must change and is it the right way to do this like I did in the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By clicking on `.test_uebergabe` the first time you are binding a function which alerts `groupid` to the click event of `.test_uebergabe_route`.

When you click on it the second time you bind a *second* function to the click event of `.test_uebergabe_route`, but this time with a different `groupid` (because you are in a different context).

Both functions will be called now when you click on `.test_uebergabe_route`, each with its `groupid`.

To avoid this kind of behavior you could try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var groupName = '';
  var groupid = '';

  $(".test_uebergabe").click(function() {
    groupName = $(this).data('groupname');
    groupid = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.modal-body').html(groupName);
    $('#dataModal').modal({
      show: true
    });
  });

  $(".test_uebergabe_route").click(function() {
      alert(groupid);
  });
});
```

By doing this you will have a single function which listens to the click event of `.test_uebergabe_route` and that will alert the current `groupid` which is now a global value.